# Is there a way to automatically keep up with jQuery updates?

Tags: jquery, cdn, google-cdn

I know about the "latest" that can be used with a CDN, but I don't want to go that route - for example, version 2.0 of jQuery drops support for some still semi-popular browsers, and so I don't want the latest, just the newest in the "1.10" family.

I could swear that I read you could do this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...and the newest version in that "family" would be added. That is, it might be 1.10.1 today, and 1.10.2 tomorrow, and it would automatically update for you.

However, that's apparently not the case; I tried that, and my page went all pear-shaped. I switched back to:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...and it switched back to displaying fine. So: is there a way to accomplish what I want, without revisiting every web site every time a new minor version of jQuery is released?

Comment: Yes, it was quite strange. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.X/jquery.min.js where, this method is properly working up to 1.8...   it will get the updated minor release.  but, not from 1.9...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below url for auto-update,

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Comment: Read the first line, he said he doesn't want that, because it will jump to a new major version.

Comment: @Barmar - sorry, i missed the exact scenario.

Comment: @Barmar It goes to 1.10.1, the latest oldIE supported version, not 2.x

Comment: @KevinB: Really? If so, that's good, but does that mean the only way to use 2.x is explicitly? If what you say is true, then "latest" might just be the best way to go.

Comment: I'd consider it bad practice to use anything but explicitly targeting a specific version due to the benefits of caching.